# How to use a specific value from database in mvc validations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have some value e.g. "Not Interested" in the database.
I need to put a validation on one of my entity using this specific value "Note Interested"

```
public class {CallNote}
{
    public datetime CallBack {get; set;}
}
```

I am trying to do in this way but getting error of Object Referance.

```
public class FutureDateAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        string Feed = "Not Interested"
        mydbContext db = new mydbContext();
        var temp = db.SavedFeedBack.FeedBack.FeedBackDropDown.Except(Feed).Any();
        if(temp.toString() == null)
        {
            return value != null && (DateTime)value > DateTime.Now
        }
        else 
            return value == null
    }
}
```

What will be the right linq query and condition in this case? I am a Newbie

Comment: At first glance, `Any()` returns a `bool`, which would never be `null`, nor would a call to `temp.toString()` ever be `null`.

Comment: Than how i can do that?

Comment: You have a bug there. You're using tostring and checking for null. When you tostring it won't be null. You mean to say string.IsNullOrEmpty (). Or perhaps test for null on temp? Although any () will return true or false.

Comment: Can you provide the name of the actual exception and the message? Would it be a `NullReferenceException`? Even though your logic with `Any()` is flawed, I don't believe that's what is causing your error.

Answer (score 0):

After this line 
var temp = db.SavedFeedBack.FeedBack.FeedBackDropDown.Except(Feed).Any();
If you want to check the value of temp, so should check for bool like

```
if(temp)
{
 // this is true
//do your logic
}
else
{
 //this is false
//do your logic
}
```